# How can I open the current HTML file in a web browser from MacVim?

Tags: browser, vim, macvim, integration

From MacVim is there a command to open the currently edited HTML file in a web browser?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do it just once, you can

```
:!open %
```

which will call the shell command `open` with the path to the current file as argument. I don't use Mac myself, but `open` seems appropriate to me. If it isn't, replace with whatever program you wish the file be opened with.

Of course you can bind a key, if you'll need it frequently:

```
:map <silent> <F5> :!open %<CR>
```

And you *may* want to

```
:set nowarn
```

to suppress warnings about unsaved file changes.

See:

- `:help :!`
- `:help cmdline-special`
- `:help 'warn'`

---

Note that you can get arbitrarily sophisticated with Vim scripting. For example, this function lets you view the current unsaved changes by use of an intermediate file:

```
function! BrowserPreview()
    if &modified
        let tmpfile = tempname()
        execute "silent write " . tmpfile
        call system("firefox " . shellescape(tmpfile))
        if delete(tmpfile) != 0
            echoerr "could not remove " . tmpfile
        endif
    else
        call system("firefox " . shellescape(expand("%:p")))
    endif
endfunction

map <silent> <F5> :call BrowserPreview()<CR>
```

(Replace both occurrences of `firefox` with `open` if that worked earlier.)

Comment: Just be sure that your file names don't have spaces. Otherwise, vim tries to open every space-delimited word as its own page. It's pretty annoying, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

`:w | !xdg-open %`

for me under Ubuntu opens the Opera browser

Comment: Can you explain the syntax of this command, and how it differs from the accepted answer?

Comment: I opened  chrome with syntax above thks

Comment: The question is about MacVim. MacVim runs on OS X. MacVim is not likely to get ported to Ubuntu. This answer is only relevant if a user has some reason to prefer xdg-open over OS X's open(1). If addressing that case, we should mention that [installing xdg-open on OS X](https://superuser.com/q/911735/115912) is possible.