# How do I use xdg-open from xdg-utils on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, installation, homebrew

I'd like to use the command line `xdg-open`. The command line is not known to my computer (Mac OSX) so I have to install the package (not sure this is the right term) that contains this command line. I think the package is called `xdg-utils`... I tried:

```
brew install xdg-open
brew install xgd-utils
brew install xdg
```

but it always returns something like

```
Error: No available formula for xdg-utils 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
```

Comment: `xdg-open` is pretty neatly tied into the freedeskop environments, and OSX' counterpart would be the `open` command. Is there a specific use case where you absolutely need `xdg-open`? If so, give us more information, please.

Comment: THanks a lot for your comment. No there was no good reason for me to use `xdg-open` instead of `open`. I just didn't know the open command. Seeking in the manual I managed to do everything I needed to do with the open command line. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: Your comment solved my problem but did not really answered the question. I now have no interest into using `xdg-open` on my machine. Do you want to make an answer out of your comment or do you want me to delete my post?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`xdg-open` is pretty neatly tied into the freedeskop environments, and OSX' counterpart would be the `open` command.

If, for whatever reason, you still like to try out `xdg-open` on OSX, here is how you get it installed manually:

```
brew install libxslt xmlto # and potentially other packages like the GNU autotools/install suite
export XML_CATALOG_FILES="/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog"
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xdg/xdg-utils.git/
cd xdg-utils
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

This will install the respective tools into /usr/local/bin, where the rest of the brew commands reside. Now, unless you install XQuartz, the usage of the xdg-utils is very limited. So:

```
brew install --cask xquartz
```

And then you need to configure your X11 applications to be xdg agnostic. Not sure how to make OSX commands xdg agnostic. Probably by fiddling around with the `xdg-mime`.